# 'None' Condition in Naive pattern matching

Tags: python

I thought `return -1 if index is None else index` will return -1 when index is `None`. But it doesn't work. Why?

```
input text: sample example for pattern matching
input pattern: and
```

Error: `%d format: a number is required, not NoneType`

```
def pattern_matching(text_string, pattern):
    for index in range(len(text_string) - len(pattern) + 1): 
        j = 0

        while(j < len(pattern)): 
            if (text_string[index + j] != pattern[j]): 
                break
            
            j += 1
  
        if (j == len(pattern)):
            return -1 if index is None else index

print("First pattern found at Index %d"%pattern_matching(text, pattern))
```

Comment: If ```j == len(pattern)``` is false, than your return statement is not evaluated and the default return from a function is ```None```. Only my guess though. Try returning -978 or something from the function after your if clause and see if it prints.

Comment: @sintribu thanks for your suggestion. Will try now